# Elasticsearch boosting score for values in array

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to implement scoring of documents based on certain values stored in array via elasticsearch. For example, if my document contain an array object like this:

Document 1:

```
{
  id: "test",
  marks: [{
     "classtype" : "x1",
     "value": 90 
  }]
}
```

Document 2:

```
{
  id: "test2",
  marks: [{
     "classtype" : "x1",
     "value": 50 
  },{
     "classtype" : "x2",
     "value": 60 
  }]
}
```

I want my output scores to be boosted by choosing boosting factor on basis of "classtype", but applicable on "value".
equivalent code would be:

```
var boostingfactor = {
   "x1" : 1,
   "x2" : 10
}
var smartscore = 0;
marks.forEach(function(mark){
      return smartscore += mark.value * boostingfactor[mark.classtype];
});
return smartscore;
```

I have tried elasticsearch query on integer values, but not sure if same can be done for values present in array. I also tried writing scripts in elasticsearch's `painless` language, but couldnt find right way to filter values based on `classtype`.

```
POST /student/_search
{
    "query": {
        "function_score": {
            "script_score" : {
                "script" : {
                    "params": {
                        "x1": 1,
                        "x2": 10
                    },
                    "source": "params[doc['marks.classtype']] * marks.value"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Expected result is scoring of 90 (90*1) for sample document 1 and 650 (50*1+60*10) for document 2 but above query fails with exception:

```
     {
        "type": "script_exception",
        "reason": "runtime error",
        "script_stack": [
          "params[doc['marks.classtype'].value]",
          "      ^---- HERE"
        ],
        "script": "params[doc['marks.classtype'].value]",
        "lang": "painless"
      }
```

Is it possible to accomplish the result via modifying script?

Elasticsearch version: 7.1.0

Answer (score 1):

I was able to read through array values using following script:

```
"script_score" : {
                "script" : {
                   "params": {
                        "x1": 5,
                        "x2": 10
                    },
                    "source": "double sum = 0.0; for (item in params._source.marks) { sum += item.value * params[item.classtype]; } return sum;"
                }
            }
```